# Creating custom host name binding for app service in terraform fails with Cannot find Certificate with name

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create custom host name binding for app service in terraform and I am using the following configuration for that

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "webapp_fqdn" {
  for_each = local.apsvc_fqdns_locations

  hostname            = each.value.fqdn
  app_service_name    = azurerm_app_service.webapp[each.value.apsvc_location_key].name
  resource_group_name = var.regional_web_rg[each.value.location].name

  ssl_state  = "SniEnabled"
  thumbprint = azurerm_app_service_certificate.cert[each.value.certificate_location_key].thumbprint
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate" "cert" {
  for_each = local.certificates_locations

  name                = each.value.certificate_name
  resource_group_name = var.regional_web_rg[each.value.location].name
  location            = each.value.location
  key_vault_secret_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cert[each.value.certificate_name].id
}
```

The code fails (sporadically) with the following error
"Cannot find Certificate with name 6CAC9XXXX."
When the error occures, I can go to portal and see the following
[image]
If I create those resources through Az PowerShell module by running the following

```
Set-AzWebApp -Name app508-resc-aa1-web-centralus-showcase-apsvc -ResourceGroupName app508-resc-aa1-web-centralus -HostNames @("showcase-aa1.np.dayforcehcm.com")
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding  -ResourceGroupName app508-resc-aa1-web-centralus  -WebAppName app508-resc-aa1-web-centralus-showcase-apsvc -Thumbprint "6CAC9XXXX" -Name "showcase-aa1.np.dayforcehcm.com"
```

it works perfectly fine and the resources are created properly.
It looks like terraform tries to create both - host name and the custom host name binding by using  one resource azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding so is it some sort of race condition that  I am facing or am I using wrong resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I see it's a problem with the `azurerm` provider. Usually, a `WaitForCompletionRef` call or equivalent function (whatever is offered by Azure-go-SDK) is made to wait until the `create/update` function is complete.

In the case of the `azurerm_app_service_certificate` resource, post `create` function call of `SDK`, the `resourceAppServiceCertificateRead` function is called immediately without waiting for the resource to be created. I think this is why you have this intermittently occuring.

```
if _, err := client.CreateOrUpdate(ctx, id.ResourceGroup, id.Name, certificate); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("creating/updating %s: %s", id, err)
    }

d.SetId(id.ID())

return resourceAppServiceCertificateRead(d, meta)
```

You can create an issue [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues) or create a PR to get this added. In the meantime, as a workaround, you can put some `sleep` for a few seconds until the resource is created. [time_sleep](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep)
could help you with this.